# Reading a CLI Progress Bar with NSTask

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, appkit, foundation

I'm working on a macOS application that uses `NSTask` to launch a Python script to perform an operation. The Python implementation displays a progress bar while the operation is running.

The Python script is using the Click package: [Click - Showing Progress Bars](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/utils/#showing-progress-bars)

`NSTask` is not reporting changes to this progress bar through the usual output readers. It is correctly notifying me of output after the progress bar has reached 100% and a final line has been written. I assume there's some sort of flushing that is not happening to inform `NSTask` that data is available.

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.arguments = ...;
task.environment = ...;
task.executableURL = ...;

NSPipe *pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
task.standardOutput = pipe;

NSFileHandle *outputHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading;

outputHandle.readabilityHandler = ^(NSFileHandle *handle) {
  NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:handle.availableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"%@", output);
};

[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];

NSLog(@"Task should have completed...");
```

**Terminal Output:**

```
  [#####     ]  50%
Command Finished.
```

**NSTask Output:**

```
Command Finished.
Task should have completed...
```

While running the command from a Terminal window, the progress bar will update and then finish with the last line. When running from an `NSTask` the only output I receive is the last line. No updates are received for the progress bar. Is there a way to receive those progress bar updates?

Same question from 12 years ago:
[read ASCII progress bar of NSStask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416680)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a determinate NSProgressIndicator to check on the progress of NSTask? - Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889006/how-to-use-a-determinate-nsprogressindicator-to-check-on-the-progress-of-nstask)

Comment: Is it missing `[outpuHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify]`?

Comment: @Willeke Not really. I'm not using an NSProgressIndicator. The progress in question is being produced by the Python script and output to the Terminal as ASCII art. I just want to be able to read that output in the same way I can read normal output from a task.

Comment: @Larme Don't think that applies if you're using the newer, `readabilityHandler` API. That method is for those waiting to receive an `NSNotification` of data being available.

Comment: The answer in the linked question doesn't call `waitUntilExit` and It observes notifications. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Willeke I have tried that and it's unrelated to the issue at hand. The problem I'm experiencing is that the `readabilityHandler` is not getting called when the Python script updates its ASCII progress bar. I *assume* this is because the Terminal is not getting flushed in a way that `NSTask` understands. (The ASCII progress bar is a single line that overwrites itself.) What I'm wondering is if there's a way for `NSTask` to still see this output even though it might not end in a newline. Once the operation has finished, a new line is emitted and the handler is called as expected.

Comment: I've done something similar in the past. How can we reproduce the issue? I'm not familiar with Python.